# callback url for API

Tags: php, json, api, codeigniter, callback

I need to integrate an API to register sms template in my codeigniter project. This is my code :

```
$postdata = array('userid'          => 'user',
                    'password'          => 'user@321',
                    'template'          => 'Demo template',
                    'callback_url'      => base_url().'API/templateCallback'
                ); 

$postdata = json_encode($postdata);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://example.com/TemplateRegistration2/registerTemplate.jsp");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$response = json_decode($response); 
print_r($response);
```

the response will be a json object like,

```
{"req_id":"809ff62f-74a9-45a5-9cb5-5e60763289af","status":"0" ,"comment":"OK"}
```

but how i read this json object in my templateCallback() function. Is there any built in function to do the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template callback is PHP file. then you should parse the request.

something like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```